# Magneto 2: How to configure a rest api only server for best performance?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, performance, nginx

I know magento have some [recommendations for the best performance](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/performance-best-practices/software.html).
And I found several articles related.

But nothing specific for servers that provide access only by the Rest API.
Because everyone includes the backend, frontend and APIs. The best of these worlds.

But I want to Know if have the best for the Rest API world. 
(using Nginx)

Comment: Use REST APIs...

Comment: @ArslanTabassum The default performance recommendations is the best for REST APIs? You recommend nothing more?

Comment: if you need ultra fast REST APIs... Use Cloud hosting as the cloud hosting have different features like dedicated server,SSD, Much more RAM & etc...

Comment: it will be increase the response time as it increased the site response time...